# Issue with Telegram bot developed in PHP

Tags: php, bots, telegram, telegram-bot

About a couple of months ago I could upload photos from my bot path with 5.5 version. Now I upgraded my PHP to 5.6 and I don't know why but I can't anymore.
This was my code:

```
$url = "https://api.telegram.org/bot".Token."/sendPhoto?chat_id=".$chat_id;

        $post_fields = array(
                'photo'     => new CURLFile(realpath("test.png"))
            );

        $ch = curl_init(); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "Content-Type:multipart/form-data"
        ));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields); 
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: What errors do you get? What happens? Are any warnings shown? Is the token still valid? Please provide more information.

Comment: Tested. Your script works without any problem on php 5.6. As Benedict say, provide more info about script behavior and error occurred.

Comment: Sincerely I don't get any error message, I only get my bot offline for about one day when I try to send a photo. Yes, the token is still valid because my bot works perfectly except for that issue.

Comment: Have you printed `$output`? There is `"ok":true ... ` in it?

Comment: I tried but the bot goes offline before the sendMessage, so it can't print anything. I really don't know how to do, I don't think that the issue would be the permissions in the FTP server...

Comment: FTP server? How is implied FTP? Do you intend image file permissions?

Comment: I host my bot on my VPS, so I put the image in the above code (test.png) in the same folder of the bot.

Comment: I really don't know. You have to investigate server config. Have you checked server logs? Also, to see if there is a problem with file permission, try to read it with file_get_contents. Also you can try using absolute path. “my bot offline for about one day” is vague and very weird. Your server stop to working or Telegram stop interacting with it?

Comment: In the server logs I didn't find any problem, or just probably they don't show them. Seems that Telegram stop interacting with it, because the other services like ts3 server work perfectly. Also, I tried using sendChatAction to see if it was mine Telegram bot problem and it sends the upload_photo action until the bot crashes completely.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function i wrote for CURL :

```
function makeHTTPRequest($method, $types = []){
    $url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'.Token.'/'.$method;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($types));
    $res = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_error($ch)){
        var_dump(curl_error($ch));
    } else {
        return json_decode($res);
    }
}
```

Then call it wherever you want :

```
var_dump(makeHTTPRequest('sendPhoto', [
    'chat_id' => $chat_id,
    'photo' => new CURLFile('test.png')
]));
```